# CallBack Function with null safety

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I have a widget like this

```
class googleMapComponent extends StatefulWidget {
   Function(LatLng pos) OnPositionChangeCallback;

googleMapComponent({
this.OnPositionChangeCallback,})
```

using nullsafety i get this error

```
The parameter 'OnPositionChangeCallback' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
```

I know using required will fix it but I don't want it to be required

Comment: You can use `Function(LatLang? pos)` to allow null values or use the `!` operator when passing values.

Comment: @DarShan the first solution doesn't work and for the second one i don't want to send value because  there is a lot of CallBack functions for this widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this function is `required` just make the parameter required and the language will enforce you to always pass a function to the constructor of `googleMapComponent`

```
class googleMapComponent extends StatefulWidget {
   Function(LatLng pos) OnPositionChangeCallback;

googleMapComponent({required this.OnPositionChangeCallback,})
```

Otherwise make the function nullable with the `?` keyword.

this is the final Answer to this question

```
final Function(LatLng pos)? OnPositionChangeCallback;
```

Comment: no, it is not required and  for the second solution you mean like this 
Function(LatLang? pos) 
if yes no it doesn't work either

Comment: The whole function should be marked as nullable `  Function(String pos) OnPositionChangeCallback` ,not just its parameter. Just remember to always check if its not null before usage. Was that what you were looking for @Ardeshirojan?

Comment: yes, this is correct thank you.i will update your answer with the final answer